# In the Data connections I don't have MYSQL as an option in VS 2010 and when I hit "Other" I still don't see MYSQL in any of those options either

Tags: .net

In the Data connections I don't have MYSQL as an option in VS 2010 and when I hit "Other" I still don't see MYSQL in any of those options either.

Answer (score 0):

You should install MySQL connector for .NET first.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Then you might see `MySQL Database` on `Choose Data Source` window.